# JSP Cannot convert 2016-01-12 14:31:22.109013 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date

Tags: java, string, jsp, date

I am trying to format a String as a date in a JSP file. Here is the code that I am using.

```
<td colspan="1" align="center">
  <fmt:formatDate type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${nppaAppInfoVO.lvl1appdte}"/>
</td>
```

A sample date I am trying to put in the fmt tag is `2016-01-12 14:31:22.109013`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message, you did not pass a `Date` but already a `String`. You cannot reformat a string with `fmt:formatDate`.

Comment: How do I convert the String to the Date and then format it within the JSP? I need to keep the date as type String.

Comment: It would be much easier to pass in a `Date`. If you just have a `String` look up `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @DrewGallagher A String is not a Date. You will need to parse your input String to get a date-time object. From that date-time object you can generate a new textual representation (a new String). Also, as your date-time object I strongly suggest using the java.time types built into Java 8 and later. The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes have proven to be confusing, troublesome, and flawed.